# Regroup properties into one list to be returned

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm new to neo4J and I'm currently building an app which includes Google pie charts to display a count of risks based on their priority. We have risks on applications and on interfaces between these applications. The goal is to display the risks of both applications (nodes) and interfaces (edges) with one legend.

I can make the chart works and display the risks on applications nodes and interfaces edges but I only managed to do it using UNION. Problem with this solution, I have two slices for each color, one for nodes and another one for edges.
Here is what it looks like at the moment :
https://ibb.co/C5WtN1w

I also tried using WITH and COLLECT but I don't really understand how they work because I got stupid results like 7k "yellow" although there are 135 yellow in total.

At the moment, my request looks like this

```
MATCH (n:Risk)
WHERE NOT (n.color="grey")
RETURN n.Priority as legend , count(*) AS count, n.color_hex AS colors ORDER by n.Priority
UNION 
MATCH ()-[r:INTERFACE]->()
WHERE (r.color="yellow" or r.color="orange" or r.color="red")
RETURN r.Priority AS legend, count(*) AS count, r.color_hex AS colors ORDER BY r.Priority
```

To clarify the properties:

- Priority : High, Medium, Low
- color : can be red (High), orange (Medium), yellow (Low), white (Not
  defined) or grey (Risk doesn't exist anymore)
- color_hex: Same as    color, but in hexa. I only use it to transfer
  the right colors to the    chart

Is it possible to count the occurrences of each color and make the count merging the colors coming from n:Risk and r:INTERFACE to have only one of each color listed?

Hope I've been clear enough, informations are running through my mind so it can be confusing.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can not process the result after **UNION**. However, we can get the expected result with the combination of **WITH**, **COLLECT**, and **UNWIND**.

To get the combined result, you can modify your query as follows:

```
MATCH (n:Risk)
WHERE NOT (n.color="grey")
WITH collect({Priority: n.Priority , color_hex: n.color_hex}) AS risks
MATCH ()-[r:INTERFACE]->()
WHERE r.color IN ["yellow", "orange", "red"]
WITH risks + collect({Priority: r.Priority , color_hex: r.color_hex}) AS allRisks
UNWIND allRisks as risk
RETURN risk.Priority as legend , count(*) AS count, risk.color_hex AS colors
ORDER BY risk.Priority
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works perfectly ! 
I need to work on those type of combinations to be able to do things like that.
Have a nice day :)